# MySQL: create a second table that stores one entity's images?

Tags: mysql, scalability

Let's say I want 5 images to my Apartment entity (table).

Should I put those 5 fields inside Apartment table, or create a seperate table "Image" with FK to apartment?

Comment: By creating a separate table, you will save space when there are fewer than 5 images and will be able to add more than 5 images without changing the Apartment table design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with a separate table. This approach is better normalized, giving you the flexibility to add any number of images and reduces the overhead on your original table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it you mean if you want to store a base64 of an image in the database, so then yes having it off to the side will help with search of the apartments, or if you want to just store the path to the image file, not it's here nor there and probable just as well to keep it all together.